# Tengo dos botones en el Action Bar que cambian el fondo de color, quisiera saber como hacer para que un solo boton cambie el fondo de color?

Tags: android-studio, condiciones, botón, actionbar, background

> Tengo dos botones en le Action Bar que cambian el fondo de color, quisiera saber como hacer para que un solo boton cambie el fondo de color?

Este es el Menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.rojo:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Rojo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mivista.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Rojo));

            break;

           case R.id.negro:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Negro",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mivista.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.Negro));

            break;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Imagen detallada: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BicZ1.jpg

Comment: Que es mivista y como obtienes la referecia? agrega el layout que carga esta Activity mediante setContentView ( )

Comment: Mi vista es un LinearLayout, lo que pasa es que no pude poner todo el código , Stackoverflow no me dejó.

Comment: Osea crack si se cambiar el color de la manera en la que lo dices , pero son 2 botones y cada uno cambia el color de fondo diferente, lo que quiero es tener un solo botón y que ese botón cambie el color, fíjate en el Switch.

Comment: Te sugiero revises [ask] para realizar tus preguntas, trata de ser especifico para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte de una forma ràpida, saludos.

Comment: Gracias crack!!

Comment: En pocas palabras que condición debo usar para que un solo botón cambie los colores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba creando una arreglo de colores y explorandolo con cada pulsacion del boton:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private int[] colors;
    private int index=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_target);
    colors=new int[2];//o la cantidad de colores que quieras
    //llena tu arreglo
    colors[0]=getResources().getColor(R.color.Rojo);
    colors[1]=getResources().getColor(R.color.Negro);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.cambiacolor:
        index++;
        if(index==colors.length)
            index=0;
        mivista.setBackgroundColor(colors[index]);
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo , funciona 